# Recursive function for the sequence that deals with the numerators of the continuous fraction representation of sqrt (2)

Tags: c, function, recursion

I tried to develop a recursive function that finds the nth term of the sequence (1,1,3,7,17,41,99,239,577,1393 ...), however, I was unsuccessful:

```
int progRec(int n){
        return 2*progRec(n-1) + progRec(n-2);}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you understand how this sequence works? If you do, you should explain it.

Comment: At what point will your function stop recursing? At stack overflow!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I understand, this sequence deals with the numerators of the continuous fraction representation of sqrt (2). I thought of explaining the progression mathematically, but without LaTex it would be very visually polluted.

Comment: @Jacobi What you wrote runs an infinite recursion. But `progRec(1)` and `progRec(2)` are the initial conditions, which cannot calculated by recursion.

Comment: @Jacobi It is good that you understand it, but you present it as a "guess the sequence" puzzle to the readers.

Comment: Your recursion is missing a stop condition.

Comment: And surely this recursion is very suboptimal, as it is calculating the same elements several times.

Comment: @beaker It's an infinite sequence, so why not let it run for infinite time?

Comment: Thanks guys! I don't know how I got to forget the break.

Comment: You probably know about this resource already, but this sequence does appear with a non recursive solution in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the stop condition. I assume it's `1 if n <= 2`:

```
int progRec(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2 * progRec(n - 1) + progRec(n - 2);
}
```

You can optimize this recursion by eliminating the second branching, which is just recalculating already visited values. Just pass the previous calculated terms as an argument:

```
int progRec(int n, int val = 1, int prev = 1) {
    return n <= 2 ? val : progRec(n - 1, 2 * val + prev, val);
}
```

You can optimize it further into a `for` loop because now it's just a tail-recursive function.

Comment: C language doesn't have default arguments

Comment: True, just use a wrapper function.

Comment: Your 2nd recursive func is a _vast_ speed improvement. I did benchmarks. For `n = 2`, `orig=87ns` and `fast=55ns`. For `n = 40`, `orig=398ms` and `fast=170ns`. For `n = 99`, `fast=270ns` [and orig is "off the charts"]. BTW, I also did the loop version, and it's _slightly_ faster, by 6ns initially down to 1ns at `n = 99`. So, time for orig grows by 50% for each increasing `n` and fast remains relatively `O(n)`

Comment: @CraigEstey The second version is a tail recursion, so no surprise it is performing similarly to loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I assumed as much because Toribio mentioned that but I wanted to code up the loop version for simplicity sake. The `-O3` versions, disassembled, seem to generate the _same_ instructions, byte-for-byte, so any speed difference is roundoff error.